# How can I calculate an inner product with an arbitrary number of columns using ddply?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I want to perform an inner product of the first D columns for each row in a data frame with a given array, `W`. I am trying the following:

```
W = (1,2,3);
ddply(df, .(id), transform, inner_product=c(col1, col2, col3) %*% W);
```

This works but I typically may have an arbitrary number of columns. Can I generalize the above expression to handle that case?

Update:

This is an updated example as asked for in the comments:

```
libary(kernlab);
data(spam);
W = array();
W[1:3] = seq(1,3);
spamdf = head(spam);
spamdf$id = seq(1,nrow(spamdf));
df_out=ddply(spamdf, .(id), transform, inner_product=c(make, address, all) %*% W);

> W
[1] 1 2 3
> spamdf[1,]
  make address  all num3d  our over remove internet order mail receive will
1    0    0.64 0.64     0 0.32    0      0        0     0    0       0 0.64
  people report addresses free business email  you credit your font num000
1      0      0         0 0.32        0  1.29 1.93      0 0.96    0      0
  money hp hpl george num650 lab labs telnet num857 data num415 num85
1     0  0   0      0      0   0    0      0      0    0      0     0
  technology num1999 parts pm direct cs meeting original project re edu table
1          0       0     0  0      0  0       0        0       0  0   0     0
  conference charSemicolon charRoundbracket charSquarebracket charExclamation
1          0             0                0                 0           0.778
  charDollar charHash capitalAve capitalLong capitalTotal type id
1          0        0      3.756          61          278 spam  1
> df_out[1,]
  make address  all num3d  our over remove internet order mail receive will
1    0    0.64 0.64     0 0.32    0      0        0     0    0       0 0.64
  people report addresses free business email  you credit your font num000
1      0      0         0 0.32        0  1.29 1.93      0 0.96    0      0
  money hp hpl george num650 lab labs telnet num857 data num415 num85
1     0  0   0      0      0   0    0      0      0    0      0     0
  technology num1999 parts pm direct cs meeting original project re edu table
1          0       0     0  0      0  0       0        0       0  0   0     0
  conference charSemicolon charRoundbracket charSquarebracket charExclamation
1          0             0                0                 0           0.778
  charDollar charHash capitalAve capitalLong capitalTotal type id inner_product
1          0        0      3.756          61          278 spam  1           3.2
```

The above example performs a inner product of the first three dimensions with an array `W=(1,2,3)` of the spam data set available in **kernlab** package. Here I have explicity specified the first three dimensions as `c(make, address, all)`.
Thus `df_out[1,"inner_product"] = 3.2`.

Instead I want to perform the inner product over all the dimensions without having to list all the dimensions. The conversion to a matrix and back to a data frame seems to be an expensive operation?

Comment: I think you should offer an example on which you have tested your code that works .... since that code will not.

Comment: Your code will only work if (col1, col2, col3) is a matrix.  This can be achieved by using either `cbind` or `as.matrix`.  I have edited your question to reflect this.  Please check and fix if incorrect.

Comment: @DWin Provided complete example. It does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strategy along the lines of the following should work:

- Convert each chunk to a matrix
- Perform a matrix multiplication
- Convert results to data.frame

The code:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    id=sample(1:5, 20, replace=TRUE),
    col1 = runif(20),
    col2 = runif(20),
    col3 = runif(20),
    col4 = runif(20)
    )

W <- c(1,2,3,4)
ddply(df, .(id), function(x)as.data.frame(as.matrix(x[, -1]) %*% W))
```

The results:

```
   id       V1
1   1 4.924994
2   1 5.076043
3   2 7.053864
4   2 5.237132
5   2 6.307620
6   2 3.413056
7   2 5.182214
8   2 7.623164
9   3 5.194714
10  3 6.733229
11  4 4.122548
12  4 3.569013
13  4 4.978939
14  4 5.513444
15  4 5.840900
16  4 6.526522
17  5 3.530220
18  5 3.549646
19  5 4.340173
20  5 3.955517
```

Comment: I thought of the matrix route but is it not possible to do directly on the data frame. What is the most efficient way of doing things? For now I have converted my data frame to a matrix and doing all operations on the matrix itself ... not going back to the data frame at all.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga Well, perhaps you should add some sample data to your question so we get an idea what you want.  I've shown how to do it without the benefit of your data.

Comment: added the output as well. I apologize for the confusion. As I look at your code more closely, I realize it achieves what I want.

Comment: What does the -1 dimension mean in R?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga It drops the first column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a column of cross-products, you could do this (assuming W had the right number of elements to match the non-"id" columns:

```
df2 <- cbind(df, as.matrix(df[, -grep("id", names(df))]) %*% W )
```

It does not appear that the .(id) serves any useful purpose, since you are not do a sum of crossproducts within id, and if you were then you wouldn't be using transform but some other aggregating function.