# R-Operating on subset of columns from dataframe with ddply

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, dot-product

I have a large-ish dataframe (40000 observations of 800 variables) and wish to operate on a range of columns of every observation with something akin to dot product.  This is how I implemented it:

```
matrixattempt <- as.matrix(dframe)
takerow <- function(k) {as.vector(matrixattempt[k,])}
takedot0 <- function(k) {sqrt(sum(data0averrow * takerow(k)[2:785]))}

for (k in 1:40000){
print(k)
dframe$dot0aver[k]<-takedot0(k)
}
```

The print is just to keep track of what's going on.  **data0averrow** is a numeric vector, same size as **takerow(k)[2:785]**, that has been pre-defined.

This is running, and from a few tests running correctly, but it is very slow.

I searched for dot product for a subset of columns, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195745/how-can-i-calculate-an-inner-product-with-an-arbitrary-number-of-columns-using-d), but could not figure out how to apply it to my setup.  ddply sounds like it should work faster (although I do not want to do splitting and would have to use the same define-id trick that the referenced questioner did).  Any insight/hints?

Comment: If neither of these answers works you really need to make this a problem with a small test case, say an 8 x 10 matrix?

Comment: @Arun's response worked well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sqrt(colSums(t(matrixattempt[, 2:785])  * data0averrow))
```

or equivalently:

```
sqrt(matrixattempt[, 2:785] %*% data0averrow)
```

Comment: Both of these worked pretty rapidly.  Thank you.  I had attempted the line with %*% before I wrote the for loop, but the order was reversed (or something else was wrong in how I set it up) so that was giving me the same value for every row.

Answer (score 2):

Use matrix multiplication and rowSums on the result:

```
dframe$dot0aver <- NA
dframe$dot0aver[2:785] <- sqrt( rowSums( 
                              matrixattempt[2:785,] %*% data0averrow ))
```

It's the sqrt of the dot-product of `data0aver` with each row in the range

Comment: Not sure, but I think the RHS must be `matrixattempt[, 2:785] %*% ...`? And I think you don't need a `rowSums`.

Comment: Not sure either. I thought he wanted the rows 2:785 to be multiplied by a vector of the same length as the number of columns. I edited my answer to reflect that since my first effort had an error or two

Comment: ah now I see what you mean and why you require the rowSums. But what I see is this: Take, for each k, `k`th row of `matrixattempt` with columns `2:785` and multiply it with `data0averrow`.